# MySQL Query order by if null

Tags: mysql

I am trying to build a MySQL query that has an order by statement. This is what I am trying to do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_product 
ORDER BY retail_price ONLY IF wholesale_price IS NULL OTHERWISE ORDER BY wholesale_price.
```

I have no idea where to start. I found an article that uses ORDER BY COALESCE but I also found that this could have performance issues.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_product 
ORDER BY ifnull(wholesale_price, retail_price);
```

Note that you don't need to *select* the value you're ordering by - it can be any expression

Comment: This really saved me! You can also add asc or desc outside of the () to change the order too. :) THANKS!