# Order data by the second field if the first field is empty

Tags: swift, core-data

I want to solve [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644343/mysql-query-order-by-if-null) using Core Data tools.

> I am trying to build a MySQL query that has an order by statement.
> This is what I am trying to do:
>
> ```
> SELECT * 
> FROM tbl_product 
> ORDER BY retail_price ONLY IF wholesale_price IS NULL OTHERWISE ORDER BY wholesale_price.
> ```
>
> I have no idea where to start. I found an article that uses ORDER BY
> COALESCE but I also found that this could have performance issues.
>
> Any advice is appreciated.

This is what I am trying to do, but this solution is obviously not the correct one:

```
let sortDescriptor1 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "wholesalePrice", ascending: true)
let sortDescriptor2 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "retailPrice", ascending: true)

fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor1, sortDescriptor2]
```

Is this task possible or not? Thanks for any advice. Unfortunately, as far as I know, there is no way to use raw SQL in Core Data requests.

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25701511/controlling-the-way-nssortdescriptor-sorts-nil-values-in-core-data#50628867) could be helpful to get the nil values sorted as you want